# Gradle release composite build with a release order

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-release-plugin

I have a gradle [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) in following directory structure.

```
.
├── component-1
├── component-2
├── component-3
└── composite-build
```

Here, all components are [multi-project builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html). Each component has implemented the [release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) and can be released individually. The `composite-build` has following `settings.gradle`.

```
rootProject.name = 'composite-build'

includeBuild '../component-1'
includeBuild '../component-2'
includeBuild '../component-3'
```

I want to execute `release` task of each component in a specific order but I couldn't find a proper way. Following are some cases that I tried and failed. In these cases individual `release` tasks are also failing due to conflicting git tag commits done by release plugin.

**Case 1:**

In `build.gradle`

```
task releaseAll {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-1').task(':release')
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-2').task(':release')
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-3').task(':release')
}
```

**Case 2:**

In `build.gradle`

```
task releaseComponent1 {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-1').task(':release')
}

task releaseComponent2 {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-2').task(':release')
}

task releaseComponent3 {
    dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('component-3').task(':release')
}

releaseComponent2.configure {
    mustRunAfter releaseComponent1
}

releaseComponent3.configure {
    mustRunAfter releaseComponent2
}

task releaseAll {
    dependsOn releaseComponent1
    dependsOn releaseComponent2
    dependsOn releaseComponent3
}
```

Sample error message:

```
> Task :component-1:component-1-release:preTagCommit FAILED
Running [git, commit, -m,  [Gradle Release Plugin] - pre tag commit:  'component-1-0.1.10'., -a] produced an error: []
Running [git, push, --porcelain, origin, main] produced an error: [error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git']

> Task :component-1:release FAILED
Release process failed, reverting back any changes made by Release Plugin.
Running [git, checkout, gradle.properties] produced an error: [error: pathspec 'gradle.properties' did not match any file(s) known to git]

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':component-1:component-1-release:preTagCommit'.
> Failed to push to remote - [To https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git
  !     refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main [remote rejected] (cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/main': is at <xxxx> but expected <yyyy>)
  Done
  ][error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/<username>/<repo-name>.git'
  ]
```

Comment: Its amazing what have you tried so far, but can you add what was the error with case1 and case2 ?

Comment: Edited the description with the error message.

Comment: and do you need to execute the `preTagCommit` as well ?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's a sub task of `release` task of net.researchgate.release plugin.

Comment: in a normal day, how do you release the subtask using command line ?

Comment: Let's say for component-1, I use `gradle release` from ./component-1 directory.

Comment: great, then my suggested answer will work like charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is always an option with gradle where you can automate and link task execution with `finalizedBy` and you can test this simple code to check how it work :

```
task A() {
    println 'taskA'
}
task B() {
    println 'taskB'
}
tasks.named("B") { finalizedBy("A") }

task C() {
    println 'taskC'
}
tasks.named("C") { finalizedBy("B") }
```

This way, by calling `gradle C` it will backtrack to execute `A` then `B` then `C`

Same way, You can do 3 tasks to get the desired ordered execution like this

```
task c1release(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.\\component-1'
  commandLine("cmd", "/c", "gradle", "release")
     doLast {
         println "component-1 release is being excuted"
     }
}
tasks.named("c1release") { finalizedBy("c2release") }

task c2release(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.\\component-2'
  commandLine("cmd", "/c", "gradle", "release")
     doLast {
         println "component-2 release is being excuted"
     }
}
tasks.named("c2release") { finalizedBy("c3release") }


task c3release(type:Exec) {
  workingDir '.\\component-3'
  commandLine("cmd", "/c", "gradle", "release")
     doLast {
         println "component-3 release is being excuted"
     }
}
tasks.named("releaseAll") { finalizedBy("c1release") }

task releaseAll() {
    println "Start releasing"
}
```

by calling `gradle releaseAll` it will execute `c1release` first then `c2release` then `c3release`

But I still wish ti know what kind of error you got with the cases you have included in your question.

Comment: In this answer, `finalizedBy` lines should be changed as follows and moved to the bottom.

`tasks.named("releaseAll") { finalizedBy("c1release") }`
`tasks.named("c1release") { finalizedBy("c2release") }`
`tasks.named("c2release") { finalizedBy("c3release") }`

Then it works like charm as you mentioned. Executing `gradle release` command instead of adding it as a dependent task will work for `mustRunAfter` as well. Thanks very much for your intuitive answer and I'm marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you, And you are right, I've altered the task orders as you suggested.