# Gradle finish clean task before running assemble tasks

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've created a custom task in the project's build.gradle file like so:

```
task buildAllForAppRelease {
    dependsOn(':clean', 'app:assembleDebug', ':clean', 'app:assembleRelease', 'app:bundleRelease')
}
```

The apks and bundles are all built, but the clean task doesn't seem to do anything.
It shows up in the build output but no files are getting deleted.

When I run the clean task directly, it does what it is supposed to do.

How can I ensure, that clean task is actually run before the other tasks?

Btw. I've set `org.gradle.paralell=true`, but that shouldn't have an influence, does it?

Comment: According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21613379/11301941) , there is no guarantee that the tasks will be ran in order using `dependsOn`.
I've encountered a similar issue before, even `mustRunAfter` did not help organize the order.
My naif solution was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74260824/11301941), messy code but strictly ordered tasks. I dont know if such a solution would be sufficient in you case. as you will need to create 3 extra tasks for each build, and a forth task `buildAllForAppRelease ` which will call all of them in the desired order after a valid clean.

Comment: @George For now, I removed clean from the dependsOn and create a Gradle 'Run Configuration' in AndroidStudio. There I put clean and buildAllForAppRelease in the tasks field and that does the trick.